# How to proxy to another URL without redirect

Tags: nginx

Is it possible to use nginx to work like this:

When going to x.com/blog  -> display the content of blog.x.com (with all the query parameters, etc) without changing the browser URL (without browser redirecting)

I tried

```
location /blog {
 proxy_pass https://blog.x.com
}
```

but that didn't work

Answer (score 1):

This nginx config works for me.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen       [::]:80;
    server_name  x.com;

    location /blog {
        proxy_pass https://blog.x.com;
        proxy_set_header Host blog.x.com;
    }
}
```