# Stop NGINX from forwarding user (reverse proxy)

Tags: nginx

For some reason, proxy_pass is forwarding the user to `google.com`, rather than just proxying the content on that page and staying on the `<domain>`. Is it possible to keep the user on `<domain>`?

Config:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name <domain>;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://google.com;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could [How to proxy to another URL without redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71015639/how-to-proxy-to-another-url-without-redirect) possibly be related to your issue?

This [post's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71016033/8461161) by [mariolu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3343490/mariolu) states adding `proxy_set_header`, secondary to your `proxy_pass` entry:

```
location /blog {
        proxy_pass https://blog.x.com;
        proxy_set_header Host blog.x.com;
    }
```